# assertions on inductive data types in CVC4

Tags: smt, algebraic-data-types, cvc4

I am trying experiment with CVC4 a bit.

```
(set-option :produce-models true)
(set-option :produce-assignments true)
(set-logic QF_UFDT)
(declare-datatypes ()
  (Color (Red) (Black))
)
(declare-const x C)
(declare-const y C)
(assert (not (= x y)))
(check-sat)
(get-value (x y))
(assert (distinct x y))
(check-sat)
(get-value (x y))
```

When I run this using CVC4 I am getting the following output

```
sat
((x R) (y R))
sat
((x R) (y R))
```

I am confused by this behaviour by this output.
If I am asserting x and y should not be equal their values must be different right?
Same is the case with distinct assertion.
Is CVC4 treating x and y as two different "objects" and hence giving the output it is giving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the same results. This is the message I get with the latest development version of CVC4 (http://cvc4.cs.stanford.edu/downloads/):

```
(error "Parse Error: stack.smt2:5.8: Sequence terminated early by token: 'Color'.

    (Color (Red) (Black))
     ^
")
```

There are a few syntax errors in your example, here is a corrected version:

```
(set-option :produce-models true)
(set-option :produce-assignments true)
(set-logic QF_UFDT)
(declare-datatypes () (
  (Color (Red) (Black))
))
(declare-const x Color)
(declare-const y Color)
(assert (not (= x y)))
(check-sat)
(get-value (x y))
(assert (distinct x y))
(check-sat)
(get-value (x y))
```

On this input, cvc4 with the option "--incremental" (which enables multiple queries), gives this response:

```
sat
((x Red) (y Black))
sat
((x Red) (y Black))
```

Hope this helps,
Andy

Comment: I had downloaded CVC4 from fedora repos. I will try this version. Thanks. Sorry for the syntax errors. Thanks